# Python: Difference between webkit and gi.repository.WebKit

Tags: python, import, webkit

I want to know what is the difference between what you get with

```
import webkit
```

and

```
from gi.repository import WebKit
```

in Python.

And, can I do the same with both?

Thanks in advance